# Columns into row in custom format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a sql table called **UsersInAuthentication** like

```
-----------------------
| AuthUserId | UserId |
|    1       |    4   |
|    1       |    5   |
|    1       |    8   |
-----------------------
```

I wish to get all users in format "(4,5,8)" as string with a single stored proc and 
If possible I also wish to insert,update,delete operations with this format.

**Edit:**
I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: How do you envisage the updates working?

Comment: I thought that I could delete everything first for AuthUserId then add new list like (12,15,18).That's why I'm asking possibility.

Comment: Add the list...to where, exactly?

Comment: To Store procedure which takes list as string (and id)
foreach item in string,insert item

I wish to call stored procedure for insert operation only once..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server, you can do this:

```
declare @list nvarchar(max)
select @list = ''

select
    @list = @list + 
        case when @list = '' then userid
            else ',' + userid end
from
    UsersInAuthentication  

set @list = '(' + substring(@list, 1, 999) + ')'
print @list
```

This is a nifty trick that builds the variable by appending each row's value to the current value of the variable. It's rather handy with table operations, and the like.

For posterity:

In MySQL, you can uses [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select 
    concat('(' + group_concat(userid order by userid separator ',') + ')') 
from 
    UserInAuthentication
```

In Oracle, you can use a cursor:

```
cursor c_users is
   select userid from usersinauthentication;
    out_users varchar2(4000);
begin
    for r_user in c_users loop
        if out_users is null then
            out_users:= r_user.first_Name;
        else
            out_users:= out_users ||', '|| r_user.first_Name;
        end if;
    end loop;
return out_users;
```

Answer (score 4):

Beats the purpose of a table a bit. Also UPDATING this can and will get tricky.

Seems like you should either rethink the design of your table, either rethink the way you are going to use it.

Comment: Methinks you're making an assumption on Myra's usage. There *are* viable reasons to do this, especially if you're passing the list to code or trying to create a CSV of some sort. I've also dealt with some fun legacy systems that require data in certain formats.

Comment: If you have no ability to do pre/post processing, or alter the way a legacy system interprets the data, then sure you are completely correct. However unlikely...

Comment: Can you give an example for the design ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQLServer:

```
--//testdata
WITH UsersInAuthentication (AuthUserId, UserId) AS (
                SELECT 1, 4
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1, 5
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1, 8
)
--// real query
SELECT  AuthUserId,
    (   SELECT      cast(UserId as varchar) + ','
        FROM        UsersInAuthentication
        ORDER BY    UserID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS UserIds
FROM    UsersInAuthentication
GROUP BY AuthUserId
```

to get:

```
AuthUserId  UserIds
----------- --------
1           4,5,8,
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual queries really depend on your [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbms). Assuming Mysql:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(UserId) FROM UsersInAuthentication;
UPDATE UsersInAuthentication SET ... WHERE UserId IN (4,5,8);
DELETE FROM UsersInAuthentication WHERE UserId IN (4,5,8);
INSERT INTO UsersInAuthentication(UserId) VALUES (4), (5), (8);
```

But note that working with comma-delimited values in a database somehow misses the point.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONCAT('(', GROUP_CONCAT(UserId SEPARATOR ','), ')')
FROM UsersInAuthentication;
```